# Change the color of the default (no) material (Cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

In the idea of having a faster workflow, I would like to know if it is possible to change the color of the default (no) material of Cycles.
I mean, if you don't assign an material to an object, it is by default a diffuse material that is light grey (0.8 white).

I like to have my objects having that default light grey because then I can give certain meshes more emphasis simply by assigning them a pure white material; which give the scene some contrast.

**How could I change the color of that default light grey so I could darken it and accentuate the contrast ?**

The idea being to be able to do this using no materials (default color), because assigning ALL meshes a material would be too long in my work process.

Actually I use a light to make my subject more bright.  But this has a lot of inconvenients, that is why I ask !

Thanks!

Comment: The default material is hardcoded as far as I can tell. "*Because assigning ALL meshes a material would be too long*" Select all `Ctrl+L`> Link Materials. How is that too long? you then get all the control you like

Comment: You would need to build your own custom build of blender to change what blender uses when there are no materials. Setting the [material override in render layers](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/post_process/layers.html#layer-panel) is a way to use one material for everything.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos thanks for those precisions.  Is it possible to better select all meshes that don't have any materials set ?

Answer (score 3):

1. Open Blender, go to the **Materials** tab from the drop down select **Material**. Make your required changes, you code enable **Nodes** and do something really complex or just change the colour. Then go to the **File** menu and **Save Startup File**.

Now when you open Blender the default material will be your custom one.
You can also do this to have a default background.

2. Alternatively, you can set a single material for all objects from the Render Layers tab. Handy for **Clay** renders.

[image]